# Final grass render is nothing like camera view

Tags: rendering

Im trying to make some grass using the hair method in Eeve, it looks nice in the viewport and in the camera view, but when i render it turns into a mish mash of hairs, what can i do?

This is what i want to render , just some grass
[image]

this is what i got--doesn't even match the ratio of the camera in the viewport
thanks for helping me this is a great comunity.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean “doesn't even match the ratio of the camera in the viewport” from what I can see they are the same.

Comment: I mean i really zoom in the grass and the final render show a much bigger area,my mistake i mean does not match the zoom . i dont know why.

Comment: It looks like the value for your hair children particles is different for the viewport and render. Changing both of them to the same value should fix the problem

Comment: Your final render doesn't show a much bigger area at all. Look at the lime-colored grass at the bottom left, they are at the same place in both views. The only difference is the number of the hair particles. The reason is, as @dunnowhattocallmyself says, the hair count for viewport and render may not be the same.

Comment: If Chris' answer doesn't work, in the Viewport Display panel, check the Amount % value

Answer (score 1):

you will find the settings in particle settings -> children:

[image]

Enter same values in "display amount" and "render amount"